# A question about probability and statistics

Tags: combinatorics

Question is:

A report is drafted about employee demographics at a certain company. Below is data gathered from the report:

> Total number of employees: **100**  
> # of married employees:
>   **60**   
> # of employees with a college degree: **40**   
> # of employees over the age of 40: **35**   
> # of married employees
>   over the age of 40: **10**   
> # of married employees with a
>   college degree: **15**   
> # of employees over the age of 40, with
>   a college degree: **10**   
> # of married employees over 40, with a
>   college degree: **5**
>
> Show that the data must be incorrect.

Basic idea might be: 

convert the counts to probabilities and use a formula which relates unions and intersections of events

But I'm really kinda lost. Is there anyone could help me out.

Many thanks!

Comment: Is this question related to *Mathematica*?

Comment: Yes, it's a _probability_ question, which is related to _Mathematica_.

Comment: Mathematica the computer software, rather than Mathematics the subject?

Comment: Unless it is made clear why the primary problem is Mathematica programming here, and not mathematical thinking, this question is off topic.

Answer (score 2):

Ignore the first line (total number of employees) for the moment.

From the remaining clues, you can construct a triple venn diagram for the three categories (married, college degree, over 40).

By the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle),
you can count the total number of people represented in your venn diagram to be
$$60 + 40 + 35 - 10 - 15 - 10 + 5 = 105,$$
but this contradicts the total count given in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

It must hold true that 100 = 60 + 40 + 35 - 10 - 15 - 10 + 5 cf 
[inclusion/exclusion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)